How do I read each object from a json file like Object.entries
I'm reading a json file with fs.createReadStream but it gives me random chunk of data.
But I need to read each key and value like Object.entries method when I used JSON.parse it throws an error SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected tokenUnderstand this error
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' } );

fileStream.on('data', (jsonObject) => {
    console.log(jsonObject);
    const data = JSON.parse(jsonObject); // THROWS AN ERROR
});
  
fileStream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('All JSON objects processed.');
});


JSON files need to be read all into memory unless you have a custom parser to parse partially loaded data

You can use JSONStream

You can use JSONStream which is exactly you want they can emit key/value pair also efficient for handling large json files
npm i JSONStream

Then you can pipe the read stream into JSONStream.parse function
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' } );

const parser = fileStream.pipe(JSONStream.parse([{emitKey: true}])); 

parser.on('data', async ({key,value}) => {
    console.log(key,value);
});
    
parser.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Finished');
});


Partially read JSON is not valid JSON. You can accumulate your JSON from the stream into a variable and parse that:
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' } );

let rawData = "";
let data = undefined;

fileStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    rawData += chunk;
});
  
fileStream.on('end', () => {
    data = JSON.parse(rawData);
    console.log('All JSON objects processed.');
});


I want to read  key and value for each entries like Object.entries. This is equal to fs.writeFileSync but I want to read one by one
